# Lucene: How to add Hits to ArrayList

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying add `Hits` to `List()` (to populate the results on web pages) this way:

```
List<ScoreDoc> results = null;

if (hits.scoreDocs.length != 0) {
  for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) { 
    results.add(scoreDoc);
  }
}
```

and it reports:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at _test.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:68)
at _test.Searcher.main(Searcher.java:80)
```

for the `results.add(scoreDoc);` line.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is `null`. You will have to create a `List` before adding items (for example use an `ArrayList`).

```
List<ScoreDoc> results = new ArrayList<ScoreDoc>();
```